# How to add 2 posts under another post? Formatting should be intact

Tags: php, wp-query, functions

The goal is to print 2 articles under an article IF the article is 200 words or less.

I've had some help over at WordPress, but the code a couple of helpful people provided I can't integrate into a seamless whole.

Here is the basic code, which works but doesn't include formatting (it just prints whole articles as a single paragraph):

```
add_filter("the_content" , "add_2_articles_if_less_than_200");

function add_2_articles_if_less_than_200($content) {

    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == "post") {
        $count = word_count($content);

        if($count < 200) { //if count is less then 200 then add two more articles from the same category
            $current_post_id = $post->ID;
            $categries = wp_get_post_categories($current_post_id);
            if(isset($categries[0])) {
                $cat = $categries[0];

                $args = array(
                            "cat" => $cat,
                            "posts_per_page" => 2,
                            "post__not_in" => array($current_post_id)
                            );
                $qry = new WP_Query($args);

                while($qry->have_posts()) {
                    $qry->the_post();
                    $content .="
                            <div class='additional_post'>
                                <h3>".get_the_title()."</h3>
                                <div class='additional_post_content'>".get_the_content()."</div>
                            </div>
                    ";
                }

                wp_reset_query();
            }
        }

    }

    return $content;
}

function word_count($content) {
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}
```

Here is the modification suggestion to print the formatting for the articles:

```
where you have

<div class='additional_post_content'>".get_the_content()."</div>

replace with

<div class='additional_post_content'>". $fmt_content ."</div>

and put this above it someplace

$unfmt_content = get_the_content();
$fmt_content = apply_filters('the_content', $unfmt_content);
```

Where do you put these suggested modifications in the original code to make it work, though?

(CREDITS go to Pramod Jodhani for the original code and Steven Stern for the modification suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost done and it's missing a key point. Here's the whole one you need to get it done (put in functions.php):

```
function add_2_articles_if_less_than_200( $content ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        // Use $post->post_content here as its content is raw - not formatted with HTML.
        $count = mb_strlen( $post->post_content, 'UTF-8' );

        // If $count is less then 200 then add two more articles from the same category.
        if ( $count < 20000 ) {
            $current_post_id = $post->ID;

            $current_post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $current_post_id );

            if ( ! empty( $current_post_categories[0] ) ) {
                $qry = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'cat'            => $current_post_categories[0],
                        'posts_per_page' => 2,
                        'post__not_in'   => array( $current_post_id ),
                    )
                );

                if ( $qry->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $qry->have_posts() ) : $qry->the_post();
                        // Remove this current function from tag `the_content` to avoid infinite loop. This is the key to make it work!
                        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'add_2_articles_if_less_than_200', 20 );

                        $filtered_post_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $qry->post->post_content );

                        // Add filter again, otherwise this whole function won't work.
                        add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_2_articles_if_less_than_200', 20 );

                        $content .= "
<div class='additional_post'>
    <h3>" . $qry->post->post_title . "</h3>
    <div class='additional_post_content'>$filtered_post_content</div>
</div>";
                    endwhile;
                }

                // Make sure you reset the query as your page does not end here.
                wp_reset_query();
            }
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

// Use priority 20 to make sure your function will run after WordPress default filter to avoid issues.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_2_articles_if_less_than_200', 20 );
```

Pay attention to the code, especially its comments! I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing is printed when I replace the old code with this one

Comment: Odd. I tested the code myself and it's working fine.

Comment: What theme are you using? I tried your code on a second domain, with a different theme, and it doesn't do anything there either (although the first code works on both sites, just that it doesn't format the content)

Comment: Mine it's a fresh WP installation with Storefront theme. Is your code written in functions.php?

Comment: In functions, yes. That's where I added it.

Comment: I made a few changes in the code, I'd say it has nothing to do with the reason why the code doesn't work for you, but it's worth trying. I also tested the code again and it's working fine. If in the end, the code doesn't work at all you might as well try debugging it *(add `var_dump('it is running')` within the function just to make sure the code is at least running)*. Also, make sure you have multiple posts in the same category and the post content matches your `$count` criteria.

Comment: OOps. I spoke too soon. It actually doesn't work as is. This code adds 2 more posts to ALL posts (even if they have 1000 words) instead of only posts that have <200 words

Comment: You have just to change the number in the code to 200. lol

Comment: Do you think your code could be counting something other than the number of words in the articles? By changing the number, I can get it to work on shorter posts only, but I don't know what number of words - 200 is definitely not 200. When I set i to around 800 it works on most articles it should, but not all. Does having images/embedded videos affect it somehow?