# Add to previous posts under post

Tags: php, date-query

**Goal**: After each post (that contains under a certain amount of words), display the two posts that were published before it in that category/tab.

I found [**this**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314726/how-to-add-2-posts-under-another-post-formatting-should-be-intact) on stack,  where they do something similar, but they're displaying the 2 most recent posts. I want to display the 2 that were published before the currently-read article, though. Is there a way to modify this code?

Comment: [WP_Query Date Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `date_query` to the $qry in the solution mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314744/161501).

```
$qry = new WP_Query(
       array(
            'cat'            => $current_post_categories[0],
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'post__not_in'   => array( $current_post_id ),

            'date_query' => array(
                                 array(
                                     'before'     => $post->post_date,
                                 ),
                            ),

              ));
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working correctly! If I find I'm wrong about that, I'll edit this comment. Great!