# How to apply 'add two more posts' to media content?

Tags: php

Goal: on media pages (image), locate the original post the images were added to (Wordpress already does this) and then print the two previous articles.

This code prints the two previous articles underneath a given POSTS [Add to previous posts under post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332176/add-to-previous-posts-under-post)

However, I also want to apply this function to WordPress MEDIA, so that underneith the media image page, the two posts that were published before the article the image is from are printed.

ie

```
Media image (from article 17)
Article 16 (complete as it would be if viewing the post)
Article 15 (complete as it would be if viewing the post)
```

Although I'm not sure if this is even possible with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

First, modify your example by specifying post type `post` and removing the `cat` and `post__not_in` arguments. Next, if you want to make sure you're looking at the parent's date and not the media's date, you'll also need to make sure to have a fallback in case someone tries to view an image that isn't attached to a post (and therefore doesn't have a parent).

```
// Make sure we can access the current $post, which is media
global $post;
// If the media isn't attached
if($post->post_parent == 0) {
    // Use the media itself's upload date
    $date = $post->post_date;
} else {
    // Get the parent post
    $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    // Use its date
    $date = $parent->post_date;
}
// Get 2 Posts
$qry = new WP_Query(
    array(
        // This pulls exactly 2 posts
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        // This pulls only Posts
        'post_type' => 'post',
        // This finds posts published before the current item
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'before' => $date,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

You'll then need to do something with the results. You can start with a simple `print_r($qry);` to make sure you retrieved the posts you intended to, then move on to a custom loop to actually display them:

```
if($qry->have_posts()):
    while($qry->have_posts()) : $qry->the_post();
        // Set up whatever html structure you want here ?>
        <hr/>
            <article>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article><?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

This will create a horizontal rule, then show the title and content of the first post, then another rule, then title and content of the second post.

Comment: I think this is getting close! It prints 4 most recent blog posts at the top of the page without any formatting, but it prints this on every page on the website, and without including the images and stuff, and it doesn't seem to specify category/tag. I would like it to only print on media files, and to print underneath the media file content, and include the images and stuff of the original articles also, and only pull posts from the same category/tag.

Comment: To display on media pages beneath the media, put the code in `attachment.php` underneath whatever code is being used to display the media itself - in a child theme so that your changes aren't overwritten when you update the parent theme. The `the_content()` call should automatically include images in the original articles, so perhaps it's something in your theme's `attachment.php` file (or lack of that file) that's causing it not to include images.